# Inserting a time stamp into a Google Sheet Macro

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for assistance in my Macro in google sheets. When I run it, I want it to create a new sheet and time stamp the tab. I have the macros to create a new sheet but looking for the code to name the new tab the current date.

Answer (score 1):

The following code renames the active Sheet.  You will need to integrate this with your code to rename the Sheet you create. The date is in the format of YearMonthDay.  You can change that by adjusting this 'yyyyMMdd'.

```
function timestampTab() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

  sht.setName(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'yyyyMMdd'));
}
```